# Removing white space from between 2 <div> tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to connect to div tags together (header & content) but am having trouble removing the white space that's between them.

I've had a look around and tried setting margins and font-sizes to 0 which was no help and inline-block worked, however, all the text alignments were messed up afterwards.

```
<!-- Pricing Boxes -->
<div id="home-pricing">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pricing-title">
                <h1>Select Your Membership Options</h1>
                <p>Each tier of membership offers a varied amount of features</p>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <!-- Signup Boxes -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="pricing-box">
                        <div class="pricing-box-title">
                            <h1>Free Trial</h1>
                            <p>30 Days Free Trial</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing-box-details">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Access to hundreds of courses</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Unlimited Email Support</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Offline Course Availability</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-times"></i> 2 Hour Priority Support</li>
                            <button>SELECT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootply Link:
https://www.bootply.com/eMYEP1J9E1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White space is caused by `<p>` bottom margin:

[image]

You should reset it to 0:

```
.pricing-box-title p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```